# No permitir caracteres en url reescrita con mod_rewrite

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

**Hola a todos tengo una reescritura con esta regla :**

```
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)$  index.php?action=$1 [L]
```

**Cuando uso la dirección por ejemplo :**  http://dominio.com/index.php?action=login

Reescribe perfectamente a **http://dominio.com/login** y si pongo al final **/** da error, lo cual es correcto como que esa url no existe, pero si pongo alguna cosa del tipo :

```
 http://dominio.com/login?test=test123
```

Sigue cargando la url del logueo, es lo que no comprendo, por qué no interpreta que esa dirección no existe, he probado de todo pero no sé como puedo prohibir que se cargue esa URL o que la de como errónea.

A ver si a alguien se le ocurre como hacerlo, porque he probado de todo y n osé cómo hacerlo o si se puede.

**Muchas gracias.**

Comment: Yo no me preocuparía demasiado por ello, simplemente no interpretes el query_string en tu PHP.  Piensa que algunas webs agregan su propia coletilla a los enlaces aunque aparentemente no sirvan para nada en el servidor destino, y el ejemplo más claro lo tienes en facebook, que le gusta agregar cosas, por ejemplo: `?fbclid=`.  Si impides todas entonces es probable que pierdas visitas. Lo que si haría sería leer la URL y si tiene query_string pegarle un redireccionamiento 301 hacia la normal, para que así conste en la cache del navegador del visitante y la próxima vez venga directamente.

Comment: Valida si $_SERVER["QUERY_STRING"] tiene datos y le metes un header con esa cabecera 301 hacia la url correcta.  Twitter también agrega cosas a sus enlaces a veces.

Comment: OKi lo digo más que nada ya sabeís por si algunos cabronazos empiezan a probar cosas y liarla, por restringir eso, un saludo y gracias a los 2 :)

Comment: ejem... "gracias a los dos"... bueno, me habré clonado sin querer :-) ... claro que van a probar cosas, eso siempre tenlo en cuenta cuando recibas datos, restringiendolos, en tu código, a los que esperas recibir en las condiciones que tu estipules (para evitar que se te cuelen) y desechando lo que no esperes recibir.

Comment: Ah no perdona jeje, error mio es que vi 2 respuestas y no me fije eras la misma persona, :) error mio un saludo